# Button cant working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on visual studio 2010 with SQL Server Management studio.

I have made a button for deleting selected rows from the table.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteSelectedMessages" runat="server" 
    Text="Verwijderen" Enabled="false" 
    OnClick="btnDeleteSelectedMessages_Click" />
```

It works perfectly for the first time when I run the page first time.

then after the button can't be clicked second time.

the code on button click event is like this.

```
protected void btnDeleteSelectedMessages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (currentGridView == null)
        setCurrentGridView();

    //controleer voor elke rij welke checkbox is geselecteerd
    foreach (GridViewRow row in currentGridView.Rows)
    {
        var cb = (HtmlInputCheckBox)row.FindControl("chkPaid");
        Guid messageID = (Guid)currentGridView.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex].Value;

        //als de checkbox is geselecteerd het bericht verwijderen
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            if (currentGridView.ID.Equals("Messages"))
                b.BussinesMessageReceiver.DeleteMessageReceiver(messageID, MessageBoxPerson);
            else if (currentGridView.ID.Equals("MessagesSent"))
                b.BussinesMessage.DeleteMessageSender(messageID);
            else //MessagesDeleted
                b.BussinesMessage.DeleteMessage(messageID, (Page.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/") + messageID));
            continue;
        }
    }
    btnDeleteSelectedMessages.Enabled = false;
    selectLocation.Visible = false;
    clearSelectedMessageSession();

    //Update the GridView
    BindGridView();
}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: You've got `Enabled="false"` set - but it's odd if it works the first time.

Comment: Yes i dine it to true. Still the same problem. It works first time then i cant click on that again.

Comment: You can do this.. Delete the on click of the button on aspx. Then go to the designer and double click on the button to generate it. Then copy paste the entire code in the new click event. That usually works out for me. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

With this code:

```
btnDeleteSelectedMessages.Enabled = false;
```

you DISable the button. Do you maybe enable that button in the Page_Load? The Button_Click handler fires *after* the Load, so you end up with a disabled button.

So you need to remove that line (why did you put it in there?)

Answer (score 1):

Button must to Enable (Enable="true") to work,

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteSelectedMessages" runat="server" Text= "Verwijderen" Enabled="true" OnClick="btnDeleteSelectedMessages_Click" />
```

Comment: show your aspx page code it help to find out problem..it may be magic that button work first time.. may be there will be other code that prevent button to work.. or other wrong things may be there..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
btnDeleteSelectedMessages.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable PostBack for your button..